# Adding downloaded file to a directory through the terminal

Tags: shell

I've been asked to download a .txt file then add it to a directory. The .txt file is in my downloads, but now I need to add it to my directory. How would I do that?

"Download the declaration.txt Add the file to your OS system to the fileProcessing directory."

I've tried this:

```bash
for file in ~/Downloads/Declaration of Independence .txt
do
    mv $file ~/fileProcessing 
done
```

Comment: This is not a programing question.

Comment: Why use a `for` loop when you only need to process one file?

Comment: I don't know what "to add it to a directory" means. You can copy the file to the directory using the command `cp`, and you can create a link to the file in the directory using the command `ln`. Intuitively I would say that creating a link reflects the idea of "addign" better than copying.